# Dynamic action button in flutter

Tags: vue.js, flutter

Like on whatsapp the search icon and more_vert icons change from Chats to Calls to Status view. If you click on the search icon when you in CHATS view u search all ur contacts, when u navigate to STATUS view u can click the search icon to search ur status. 
Also, the items in more_vert icon when u on STATUS view are: Status Privacy, and Settings, and when you navigate to CALLS view the items change to: Clear call log, and Settings.
How these get update each time the route changes forms CHATS to CALLS to STATUS  view is what I wish to implement. If u are using whatsapp u know this.

Thanks for any help on this using flutter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you complete this? If you got the solution please reply to me. I'm also stuck on the same problem for the last three days.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use for your navigation? If you are using something like `tabView` or `pageView`, you can have a `state` set equal to the index of the page.

From there you can do some inline script such as...

**For 2 Pages:**
assuming `int index = 0`

`index == 0 ? FloatingActionButton(attributes for index 0) : FloatingActionButton(attributes for index 1)`

This is a shorthand ternary operator.

**For more than 2 pages its a bit harder:**
assuming `int index = 0`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildFAB(context);
  }

  FloatingActionButton _buildFAB(context) {
    switch(index) {
      case 0: {
        return FloatingActionButton(attributes for index 0);
      }
      break;
      case 1: {
        return FloatingActionButton(attributes for index 1);
      }
      break;
      case 3: {
        return FloatingActionButton(attributes for index 2);
      }
      break;
      //more for each page
    }
  }
```

There are probably hundreds of ways this can be done, and not seeing any of your code this is the best I can do. Hopefully, this helps even a little bit!

Comment: You have appbar with icons like more-vert search icon at the top and tabs at the bottom of the appbar. Now u navigate to new page when u click on a tab. What I need is that as u click on the tab and navigate to another router the icons at the top of the appbar changes. Like more_very icon could contain 3 items on a tab view and different items when you navigate to another view. Like Whatsapp, when u are on chats screen ur search icon takes to where you can search for chats and when you are in call screen ur search icon takes you to where you can search calls